# How to drag full screen window to the other workspace in unity

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, workspaces, window

As the title

I can drag the window to the other workspace if the window is not full screen. I need restore the window first before I move it to the other workspace. Any shortcut?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume there are a number of ways to do this, but the two I most commonly use are:

- Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, and press an arrow key to move it to the next workspace in that direction. If you do this correctly, a little "mini-view" of the workspaces should pop up, showing the window moving to the new workspace, as well as an arrow pointing in the direction it's moving.
- Press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> (or press the `Workspace Switcher` button on the launcher), which will zoom you out to view all four workspaces. From here, you can grab any window with your mouse and move it between any of the workspaces.

Both of these methods should maintain the full screen state of the window.